# How to get sorted data from Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, getvalue

How I can get **TOP three** users(maybe in HashMap) with name and userScore from all users in Firebase Database? HashMap must be **order by userScore**. Or get **`ArrayList<User> usersList`** with three sorted users by userScore.
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGztR.png)

```
{"top_clicker_db" : { 
    "total_clicks" : 3401,
    "user" : {
      "-KkePRVzO_lLLgp7fqX0" : {
        "name" : "fly",
        "userScore" : 2000
      },
      "-KkjWk0L2lR8RwUXF2Bd" : {
        "name" : "lg",
        "userScore" : 24
      },
      "-KkjjxNw8fj_XG9uUPEg" : {
        "name" : "fjfg",
        "userScore" : 304
      },
      "-KkjoakdLIjYlBEM1pkq" : {
        "name" : "Geny",
        "userScore" : 100
      },
      "-KklVAOkk2WJaRmH9cKk" : {
        "name" : "fly",
        "userScore" : 941
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need:

```
fly=2000;
fly=941;
fjfg=304;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved the problem.** But now I think how I can limited my `list` only for 3 users.

```
userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                getTopThreeUsers((Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

private void getTopThreeUsers(Map<String, Object> users) {
        HashMap<String, Long> namesAndScores = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : users.entrySet()) {
            Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
            namesAndScores.put((String) singleUser.get("name"), (Long) singleUser.get("userScore"));
        }
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Long>> set = namesAndScores.entrySet();
        List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Long>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Long> o1, Map.Entry<String, Long> o2) {
                return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });

        topName1.setText(list.get(0).getKey());
        topName2.setText(list.get(1).getKey());
        topName3.setText(list.get(2).getKey());

        topScore1.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(0).getValue()));
        topScore2.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(1).getValue()));
        topScore3.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(2).getValue()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem in easiest way possible i recomand you change you database structure like this:

```
{"top_clicker_db" : { 
    "total_clicks" : 3401,
    "user" : {
      "-KkePRVzO_lLLgp7fqX0" : {
        "fly" : 2000
      },
      "-KkjWk0L2lR8RwUXF2Bd" : {
        "lg" : 24
      },
      "-KkjjxNw8fj_XG9uUPEg" : {
        "fjfg" : 304
      },
      "-KkjoakdLIjYlBEM1pkq" : {
        "Geny" : 100
      },
      "-KklVAOkk2WJaRmH9cKk" : {
        "fly" : 941
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You need a single child with `the user name as the key` and `the score as the value`. The benefits of this structure is that you need to **query just once**. To achieve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("top_clicker_db").child("user").child(userId);
Query query = yourRef.child(userName).orderByValue().limitToFirst(3);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d("TAG", dataSnapshot.getKey() + "=" + dataSnapshot.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank. But I can't change my database structure. In my app i get User object. But I'll think about it.

Comment: Ok. Keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

You said you cannot change your database structure in the comment in @alex-mamo 's answer, but how about adding a new node?

If you can, denormalize your data may also be a good solution. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

```
"total_clicks" : 3401,
"user" : {
  "-KkePRVzO_lLLgp7fqX0" : {
    "name" : "fly",
    "userScore" : 2000
  },
  "-KkjWk0L2lR8RwUXF2Bd" : {
    "name" : "lg",
    "userScore" : 24
  ...
},
"scores" : {
  "-KkePRVzO_lLLgp7fqX0" : {
    "fly" : 2000
  },
  "-KkjWk0L2lR8RwUXF2Bd" : {
    "lg" : 24
  },
  ...
}
```